# Encountering error while trying to start postgresql server with a newly initialize database in a different location with pg_ctl command

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

When I run the following command to start the server with database in a different location:

`/bin/pg_ctl -D /path/to/db -l logfile start`

I face the following error :

`waiting for server to start..../bin/sh: 1: cannot create logfile: Permission denied stopped waiting pg_ctl: could not start server Examine the log output.`

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling that the command is unable to create logfile in the directory you are trying to create. The command you have mentioned is trying to create logfile in the bin directory and with the user you are trying to do this does not have the privilege of writing in that directory. I suppose you want to create the logfile in the path where your database cluster is and when you run the `pg_ctl` command with only `-l` logfile it will try to create it in the current active directory.

To solve the issue try the following command

```
/bin/pg_ctl -D /path/to/db -l /path/to/db/logfile.log start
```

Comment: Yes, the cammand indeed worked. My current directory was /lib/postgresql/bin where only the the root user has the write privilege therefore it was denying to generate the logfile and also when i would try to run it with 'sudo' command it would refuse to do so.

Comment: pg_ctl can not be run as root i think for security reason. For more information about pg_ctl you can read this [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/app-pg-ctl.html).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you run that in the current directory where you initialized a database using `initdb`. Also, the `logfile` should be present in this directory.

```
pg_ctl -D /database/directory/database -l /database/directory/logfile start
```

This should work.

Answer (score -1):

This error is arising due to the process lacking the appropriate permissions to inscribe to the logfile at the spot where you're attempting to generate it. The PostgreSQL process commonly operates as a specific user (typically 'postgres' or similar), and that user needs to have write access to the directory where you're aiming to write the log file.

Here are several steps you could take to troubleshoot this issue:

Verify your current user: Make sure that you're running the pg_ctl command as a user holding the correct permissions (for instance, the postgres user). You can switch to the postgres user with the command sudo -i -u postgres.

Assess the logfile's location permissions: Confirm the directory in which you're trying to spawn the logfile permits write access for the user under which PostgreSQL is executing. You can transform the permissions of a directory with the command chmod and the ownership with the command chown. For instance:

```
sudo chown postgres:postgres /path/to/logfile/directory
sudo chmod 700 /path/to/logfile/directory
```

The above commands alter the ownership of the directory to the postgres user and group, and fix the permissions such that only the owner (postgres) can read, write, and execute files in the directory.

Examine your data directory permissions: Similarly, PostgreSQL must have read/write permissions for the new data directory (/path/to/db). You can set these permissions in the same manner:

```
sudo chown postgres:postgres /path/to/db
sudo chmod 700 /path/to/db
```

After you've scrutinized and modified the permissions and ownership as needed, you should be capable to initiate the PostgreSQL server with your new data directory. If you continue to encounter problems, kindly inspect the PostgreSQL server's logs for any error messages, as these will aid in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, 
daniya shyanne!

All eight of your answers here since you joined 3 days ago appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.